# Why DefaultHttpClient.execute fails for not finding a certifcate when accessing a regular http address?

Tags: java, jboss, openshift

We're using a java application, running on jboss and rhel image. This app works as a forward proxy; users must authenticate on it and then all requests are forward to another mvc app and responses redirected to forward proxy/authentication app. It also uses a webservice to check user credentials. This check on webservice works just fine.

The mvc behind the java forward proxy is a .NET mvc application. This architecture works fine on our physical servers, but I'm struggling for more than a week to get it working on openshift pod.

After credentials are successfully validated against the web service, the java app tries to reach a resource on mvc app, which after making sure that the caller is safe (it actually just receive a get request with a client code, and check if the code is valid http://Mvc/Administration/Administration?membershipNumber=409738467360), redirect the request to the Welcome view.

Looking at the log files, I can see that the mvc app returns `200` first for the get request. It also receives the redirect (302) to Welcome view (note that all this communication is done through http, not https).

After that, it crashes.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Here is the DefaultHttpClient redirect code:

```
httpClient.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy(){
        @Override
        public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)
                throws ProtocolException {


            logger.info("Reverse proxy response: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            boolean isRedirect = super.isRedirected(request, response, context);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            logger.info("Is redirect " + isRedirect);
            if (!isRedirect) {
                if (responseCode == 301 || responseCode == 302) {
                    logger.info("Forward proxy returning true");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            logger.info("Forward proxy returning " + isRedirect);
            return isRedirect;

        }
    });
```

I'm quite clueless on what's wrong, don't what to try. Any help is appreciate!

Thanks!

Comment: I posted my handmade solution, let me know if you want more explanations.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I'll try it and get back to you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the connection can't be secured with the parameter you gave. As you can't *handshake*, you may be **on a false website** pretending to be `xxx site`.
If that's the desired behavior, you can use this workaround:

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext(), new NoopHostnameVerifier());
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setMaxConnPerRoute(20)
        .setMaxConnTotal(200)
        .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
        .build();
```

This will basically disable the certificate handshakes.

Comment: Hi Nathan, it worked, I'm not getting an exception related to SSL. But now I'm a 302 loop when trying to reach /Home/WelcomeView. But for this query, the solution worked, thanks a lot!